# Symfony/DQL - Find a row with 2 users in a many-to-many

Tags: php, database, symfony, dql, query-builder

I'm working on a Messenger System separated in 3 entities

- Conversation, with the name of the conversation
- Participant, a Many-to-many relationship between a Conversation and a User, where the Participant can be the owner, a moderator, or a simple user
- Message, sent by a participant inside a Conversation

And i wish to find a Conversation with a user A and B, where both of them are Participants of the Conversation. Any idea how to ? 
Thanks for reading :)

Comment: have you tried using [joins](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins)? Can you show us what youve tried so far?

Comment: Actually i didn't do anything yet, i'm thinking about it. 
The best idea i'd have is to use the Exist keyword. I've read you can use multiple WHERE using EXIST. But i'm failing at using it in doctrine.

Comment: I finally figured out how to solve this problem using SQL. Now, i have to make it work using DQL.
`SELECT * FROM conversation 
WHERE 
 EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM participant WHERE participant.user_id = 3
        )
    AND EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM participant WHERE participant.user_id = 4
        )`

Answer (score 0):

I've spent some time thinking and it took me like a damn hour to find the solution. This will also work into finding the common friend of two users.

```
    $firstParticipant = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $firstParticipant
            ->select('pfirst')
            ->from('EvoMessengerBundle:Participant', 'pfirst')
            ->where('pfirst.user = :pfirstuser')    
            ->andWhere('pfirst.conversation = c')
    ;

    $secondParticipant = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $secondParticipant
            ->select('psecond')
            ->from('EvoMessengerBundle:Participant', 'psecond')
            ->where('psecond.user = :pseconduser')
            ->andWhere('psecond.conversation = c')
    ;

    $q =    $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

    $q
            ->select('c')
            ->from('EvoMessengerBundle:Conversation', 'c')
            ->where($q->expr()->exists($firstParticipant->getDql()))
            ->setParameter(':pfirstuser', $first)
            ->andWhere($q->expr()->exists($secondParticipant->getDql()))
            ->setParameter(':pseconduser', $second)
            ->setMaxResults(1)
        ;

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
```